# If a monotonic function and its inverse equals to itself, then it must be function $x$?

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is a monotonic function on [0,1] with property $f = f^{-1}$, then $f(x) = x$ for all $x$ in this interval.

I don't how to determine if this statement is true or not. Any hints and how do I prove or disprove it?

Comment: How about the function $f(x)=1-x$? In fact take any function which is symmetric about the line $y=x$ and is bijective from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Also how about $\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Comment: is your function allowed to be ether monotone increasing, or monotone decreasing, or only monotone increasing? (The answer just posted answers the latter case positively, and the comments answer the former case negatively.)

Comment: @Mirko only states monotonic function, I think it implies either non-increasing or non-decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is increasing. If $f(x) > x \to f(f(x)) > f(x) \to x = f^{-1}(f(x)) = f(f(x)) > f(x)$, contradiction. Similarly $f(x) < x$ leads to contradiction. Thus $f(x) = x$.

Comment: how about the comments just posted above

Comment: The first implication is correct if $f$ is increasing.

Comment: I'm kind of confused, above comments have provide counterexamples, how is statement been proved?

Comment: If you add the part: $f$ is monotonically increasing then the proof works because the examples used in both comments are functions that are decreasing.